# Can a graph be both bipartite and tripartite?

Tags: graph-theory

I am confused with the definition of partite graph. Is it possible for a graph be both bipartite and tripartite or more?For instance, for a bipartite graph which is 2verticesX2vertices, can I divide it into 1X1X2 sets of vertices and call it tripartite?

Comment: Yes, a graph with no edges can be, as can some other graphs with $6$ partitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k$-partite just means $k$-colourable. If a graph is $2$-colourable (and it has enough vertices) then it is certainly $3$-colourable as well. Simply take a $2$-colouring and choose some vertices from one colour class to assign a third colour to.